# Import Summary Links Collection

Tags: publishing-page, import

I am trying to insert summary links into a custom content type.

```
PublishingPage newPage = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(filename, layout);
                newPage.Title = page.NewPage.Title;
                newPage.Update();

            // Update the fields on the new page
            SPFile file = currentWeb.GetFile(newPage.Url);
            SPListItem newPageItem = file.Item;
            newPageItem["Contact Info"] = page.NewPage.ContactInfo;                
            newPageItem["Summary Links"] = resolveSummaryLinks(page.NewPage.SummaryLinks); 
            newPageItem.Update();
```

my "resolveSummaryLinks" code just creates a "SummaryLinkCollection" and returns that.  However; the new page doesn't have any value for the "Summary Links" field.
How should I be populating this field?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to figure it out.  My collection needs to be serialized to a string THEN the xml declaration that is created needs to be removed.

```
SummaryLinkCollection collection = new SummaryLinkCollection();
//Other code to populate the collection
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
collection.Serialize(writer);
string x = string.Empty;
writer.Flush();
x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
string y= x.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "");
return y;
```

The removal of the xml declaration was very important, if not done, then trying to add the value would raise an exception that the xml declaration was unexpected.